# Android - Trouble using CommonWare's locpoller

Tags: android, service, location, broadcastreceiver

I've been trying to move the gps of any of my apps into a service and Im having a really hard time. Using the services has always been a pain in the ass for me for some reason. Opengl no problem.....passing simple data from a service into an activity has been killing me for the past 3 days now.

Since I found this to be a complete pain in the ass I had been looking around on here to find some examples and came across commonware's locpoller. I had it up and running in no time but before I knew it my code became extremely convoluted and mixed between samples I found on here and the demo commonware has in the git repo.

Can somebody please point me towards something that shows how to initiate the service, set up a broadcast receiver, and then pull data out of the receiver into my activity. It sounds really easy but in practice it has been making me pull my hair out. I dont need some one to hold my hand I just need to see how you get data out of broadcasts from services into the activity your service is bound to. With messages and handlers and everything else Im just confused to hell at this point.

Any help would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can somebody please point me towards something that shows how to initiate the service, set up a broadcast receiver, and then pull data out of the receiver into my activity.

Your question title does not seem to match this request. Be that as it may...

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Service/Downloader) has an activity that sends a command to a service, with the service delivering results via a broadcast `Intent`.

> I just need to see how you get data out of broadcasts from services into the activity your service is bound to.

Why would you need a broadcast if you are using the binding pattern? You can pass in some sort of listener object from the activity to the service, which the service can call when events occur. Personally, I dislike the binding pattern and avoid it where possible.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply Common. Because I have had so much trouble in the past using the services and getting them to work I end up using what ever works first whether its binding or what ever. To be honest I dont know why I would need to bind with a broadcast. The documentation is quite a lot to digest using either route and I think Im just totally confused at this point. So in your opinion I should just ditch binding in favor of waiting for broadcasts? If so how can I get data out of the broadcast.

Comment: I can see in your demo how you write gps data to a file but how would I get that location data into an activity?

Comment: Ill look over that sample project you posted in your response. I didnt notice it was a link :p

Comment: @Jamesandresakis: "So in your opinion I should just ditch binding in favor of waiting for broadcasts?" -- I can't make such a recommendation with only the info that you have provided here. I am more saying that the combination of binding and broadcasts seems unusual. "If so how can I get data out of the broadcast" -- put extras on the `Intent` that you broadcast, and read those extras back out of the `Intent`. "I can see in your demo how you write gps data to a file" -- that demo is for `LocationPoller`, which has little to do with your problem.

Comment: Hey Commons thanks again for the help :) after stepping away from the computer, eating copious amounts of mexican food, and having a couple of beers I was able to use your LocationPoller service. I just had to create my own broadcast receiver and tailor it to my needs. Much simpler than what I was previously trying to do.  Looking at your DownloadFragment class did the trick.